# Applying Color Saved in Session to Linear Gradient

Tags: css, session, background-image, linear-gradients

I have a class in which an image stored in session is placed on top of a background color stored in session. I would like to add a linear gradient to the user's image that takes the color of the background. How can I do this?

Here's what I have:

```
.headerimagecell {
      background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, 
        <%=headerbgc %>
      ),
      url('./<%=filePath %>');
    }
```

Ideally, I'd like to get something similar to this:

```
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, 
    rgba(0,0,0,0.9) 0%, 
    rgba(0,0,0,0) 20%,
    rgba(0,0,0,0) 80%,
    rgba(0,0,0,0.9) 100%
  ),
  url(picture.jpg);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying a few things out, I decided to use a radial gradient with a transparent property:

```
.headerimagecell {
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 400px 225px;
    min-width: 400px;
    background-image: url('./<%=filePath %>');
    background-image: -webkit-radial-gradient(transparent, <%=headerbgc %>),  url('./<%=filePath %>');
    background-image: -moz-radial-gradient(transparent, <%=headerbgc %>),  url('./<%=filePath %>');
    background-image: -o-radial-gradient(transparent, <%=headerbgc %>),  url('./<%=filePath %>');
    background-image: radial-gradient(transparent, <%=headerbgc %>),  url('./<%=filePath %>');
    border-radius: 10px;
}
```

This displays my image with the color stored in session laying over the edges of the image. I imagine the same would work for linear gradient as well.